# Перенос данных из csv файла в таблицу postgresql

Tags: postgresql, csv

Пытаюсь считать данные из файла в таблицу postgresql. Проблема заключается в том, что файл большой(400000 значений) и весьма специфичный. В строках может не быть некоторых значений, то есть даже через запятую пустых значений нет, а исправлять его невозможно ввиду его громоздкости.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно либо csv привести в тонус и [об copy втянуть в постгрес](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/import-csv-file-into-posgresql-table/), либо написать скрипт, понимающий ваш csv и вставляющий данные в БД.